# When was Grothendieck attending the Seminaire Cartan?

Tags: homological-algebra, math-history

If I recall correctly, Grothendieck was at the Seminaire Cartan prior to writing his Tohoku article, and the homological algebra there influenced his work. (I also recall a quote about Grothendieck loathing diagrams (or spectral sequences?) at the seminar.) But now I cannot find a reference for this fact. Any pointer to one would be appreciated.

(I know Grothendieck was at the Seminare 1948-1949 (50?), but today I started wondering if he was there any sooner time before 1955, which is why I ask.)

Comment: You may want to ask the same question at [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com).

Comment: numdam has digitiesed all these seminares you could search for those by Grothendieck, this may give some idea.

Comment: I believe it was in 1948, when he was 20 years old.